# Possible Fields?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Is there an algebraically closed field which is a 1-dimensional vector space (as opposed to complex numbers which are 2-D)?

Also is there a complete $\aleph_0$ field?

Comment: The complexes are one-dimensional over the complexes...

Comment: Is that right?  I've only ever considered them as an isomorphism of $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: Yes. In general, vector spaces can be over an arbitrary field, not just the reals.

Comment: So, as another example, $\mathbb{C}^2$ has dimension four over the reals but dimension two over the complexes.

Comment: (And just to now point out the obvious: every algebraically closed field is a one-dimensional vector space over itself.)

Comment: Does that mean that the complex numbers have the same cardinality as the real numbers?  And thus could (somehow) be used to represent a geometric line?

Comment: Or maybe the fact that they're unordered rules out the 2nd question?

Comment: I think you're running a lot of ideas together. As a *set*, the complexes are isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$, but $\mathbb{R}^k$ has the same cardinality as $\mathbb{R}$ for any positive integer $k$. (So yes, the complexes have the same cardinality as the reals.) But vector spaces carry more than sets; that's why dimension depends on the underlying field, and why higher dimensions don't mean higher cardinality. Lastly, It isn't obvious what you mean by "representing a geometric line." If "line" means "one-dimensional vector subspace," then you can think of $\mathbb{C}$ as the "complex line."

Comment: (Cont.) in other words, the idea of a line doesn't have anything to do with cardinality. The interval $(0,1)$ has the same cardinality as the reals, but we don't call it a line.

Comment: Cool beans.  Your explanations (and [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve)) have answered the questions I had related to my first question.  Do you have any thoughts on a whether there exists a complete field/ metric space with cardinality $\aleph_0$?  And if so, could it be constructed from $\Bbb N$?  Or if not, why?

Comment: Yes. There are countable algebraically closed fields. You can get them in two ways: as the algebraic closure of a finite field, or as the closure of a countable field. See http://planetmath.org/cardinalityofalgebraicclosure

Comment: I meant *complete* as in every Cauchy sequence in the set converges to an element in the set -- not that it's algebraically closed.  Are there any countable, *complete* fields?

Comment: @user161978 "Cauchy sequence" doesn't mean anything in the context of an arbitrary field! What is the metric? (There is in fact one standard answer to this question, which is to require an [absolute value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value_%28algebra%29) and consider the induced metric).

Comment: You can put the discrete metric on any field you like to get a complete metric space, but otherwise the answer is no-any complete metric space is either uncountable or has isolated points, so if you want your metric to be translation invariant a topological field is either uncountable or discrete.

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks to all of you guys for clearing these things up for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $F$ is an infinite field and $n<|F|$ as cardinal numbers, then the cardinality of any vector space considered over $F$ of dimension $n$ is equal to the size of $F$. In particular, since $\Bbb C\cong\Bbb R^2$ as vector spaces considered over $\Bbb R$ and $2<|\Bbb R|={\frak c}$, we know $\Bbb C$ and $\Bbb R$ are equinumerous.

Given a field $L$ and a subfield $K$, the space $L$ satisfies all of the axioms of being a vector space over the scalar field $K$. Since we can vary $K$, we can vary the field of scalars over which we are considering $L$ as a vector space. Every field is one-dimensional over itself, so in particular any algebraically closed field is one-dimensional over itself.

In order to speak of completeness or Cauchy sequences on a field, there needs to be some kind of metric involved. Often we speak of metrics induced from absolute values on fields. The trivial absolute value induces the discrete metric which is always complete. Otherwise, any algebraic extension of $\Bbb Q$ or $\Bbb F_p(T)$ will have nontrivial absolute values classified by Ostrowski's theorem and under none of them is the field complete.

More generally, if the topology on $F$ induced from some metric makes $F$ a topological field (so that open sets remain open upon translation), and $F$ is countable, then the metric cannot be complete but not discrete, as Kevin remarks in the comments. The Baire category theory implies that every complete metric space with no isolated points is uncountable, the contrapositive of which is that every countable complete metric space has isolated points. If $x\in F$ is isolated, then by translation-invariance every point is isolated, so the topology is discrete and hence the metric is too.